# accessing dynamic variable name in github actions

Tags: shell, github-actions

I want to access value of dynamic variable name which in effect is c_ip1, c_ip2
How do I construct this in github actions workflow ?.
Currently I am getting error if I access the following way:

```sh
val="needs.build.outputs.c_ip$ip"
echo ${!val }
```

Thanks in advance

````
on: [push]


jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      c_ip1: ${{ steps.set_c.outputs.c_ip1 }}
      c_ip2: ${{ steps.set_c.outputs.c_ip2 }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
       include:
         - index: 1
           deploy: "dev" 
         - index: 2
           deploy: "prod" 
    steps:

      - id: set_c
        run: |
          res=10
          if [ ${{ matrix.index }} = "dev" ]; then
            echo "::set-output name=c_ip1::$res"
          else
            res=5
            echo "::set-output name=c_ip2::$res"
              
          fi
        continue-on-error: true     

  upgrade-c2:
    name: another job
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
       include:
         - index: 1
           deploy: "dev" 
         - index: 2
           deploy: "prod" 


    steps:
    - run: |
         ip=${{ matrix.index }}
         val="needs.build.outputs.c_ip$ip"
         if [ ${{ matrix.deploy }} = "dev" ]; then
           #echo ${{ needs.build.outputs.c_ip[$ip] }}
           echo ${!val}
         else
           #echo ${{ needs.build.outputs.c_ip[$ip] }}
           echo ${!val}
         fi
      continue-on-error: true```
````

Comment: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25634

Answer (score 1):

As you already in the context you should use `matrix.index`

````yaml
    steps:
    - run: |
         val="${{ needs.build.outputs.c_ip[matrix.index] }}"
         if [ ${{ matrix.deploy }} = "dev" ]; then
           #echo ${{ needs.build.outputs.c_ip[matrix.index] }}
           echo ${!val}
         else
           #echo ${{ needs.build.outputs.c_ip[matrix.index] }}
           echo ${!val}
         fi
      continue-on-error: true```
````

Comment: It is giving an error for echo ${!val} saying no such variable found. when I do ${val} it dosen't print the variable name